# Converting numeric character reference to actual character

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I receive some string with Japanese chars inside represented in numeric character reference format and need to convert them into proper Japanese char for display.

I wrote the following JavaScript to do the conversion

```
var regex_num_set = /&#\d+;/g,
var strJapanese = "Here is some Japanese text: &#12415;&#12394;&#12373;&#12435;&#12289;"

var charSet = str.match(REGEX_NUM_CHARSET); 
if(charSet && charSet.length > 0) {
    charSet.forEach(function(c) {
        str = str.replace(c, String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c.replace(/[&#;]/g, ''))));
    })
};
```

This does the job but is there any more efficient way to define the regular expression and do a simple one-line replacement?

Comment: If it works, why not post that at [Codereview.se]?

Comment: I hesitated between the two and come back to stackoverflow because I'm asking for a technical question on how to define an alternative regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace, why not to use `replace`?

```js
var regex_num_set = /&#(\d+);/g;
var strJapanese = "Here is some Japanese text: &#12415;&#12394;&#12373;&#12435;&#12289;"


strJapanese = strJapanese.replace(regex_num_set, function(_, $1) {
  return String.fromCharCode($1);
});  


document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(strJapanese,0,3));
```

Note that this code doesn't handle hex escapes (`&#xMMM`) and "astral plane" characters (like `&#127812;`). For production use I'd suggest you look around for a lib there does the job correctly.